# Scroll through the side bar of a page using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

How do I scroll through just the side bar of a page and not the whole page?

I saw this [solution](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1168#issuecomment-339683549) but I don't know exactly how to get x and y. Using this doc as an example, how do I scroll through the scroll view on the side bar.

[image: Nodejs Documentation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some ways you can scroll this part to its bottom:

```js
'use strict';


const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      args: ['--start-maximized'],
    });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 600 });

    await page.goto('https://nodejs.org/api/');
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const container = document.querySelector('#column2');
      container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
    });

    await page.waitFor(3000);

    await page.goto('https://nodejs.org/api/');
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const container = document.querySelector('#column2');
      container.scroll(0, container.scrollHeight);
    });

    await page.waitFor(3000);

    await page.goto('https://nodejs.org/api/');
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const container = document.querySelector('#column2');
      container.scrollBy(0, container.scrollHeight);
    });

    await page.waitFor(3000);

    await page.goto('https://nodejs.org/api/');
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const container = document.querySelector('#column2');
      container.scrollTo(0, container.scrollHeight);
    });

    await page.waitFor(3000);

    await page.goto('https://nodejs.org/api/');
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const lastElementInContainer = [...document.querySelectorAll('#column2 li')].pop();
      lastElementInContainer.scrollIntoView();
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: What is the difference between `scroll`, `scrollBy`,`scrollTo`. I am just going through the docs and I don't really see any? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions

Comment: and also why do you wait after each of the options, is the code expected to continue or you are trying to show different ways of solving the task?

Comment: Yes, waiting is just to illustrate the effect of different ways. `scrollBy()` uses options relatively (scrol by some amount from the current position), `scroll()` and `scrollTo()` [have the same effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll#Notes) and use options absolutely (scroll to the absolute coordinates from any position).